# Embedding a form from a third party using react functional components

Tags: reactjs, embed, react-functional-component

I am trying to embed a form from a third party. It seems to not like the "key" for some reason. Can anyone help? I have also tried to build it through the DOM and was unsuccessful. Error below:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "}"

```
 <script>
  EmbedManager.embed({
  key: "key",
     ^
  width: "100%"
  });
 </script>
```

Below is my current code:

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Contact = () => {

    return (
        <Container style={{paddingTop: 100}}>

            <Container>
                <div style='display:none;' id="contact-form">
                    <a name="formid" id="formAnchorid"></a>
                    <script src="https://fs23.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?id"></script>
                    <script>
                        EmbedManager.embed({
                        key: "key",
                        width: "100%"
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </Container>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Contact;
```

Comment: You can't embed scripts in JSX this way. Rather, you should include these script tags in the index.html file for the project.

Comment: Was trying to avoid that, okay thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try curly bracket to write jsx like this:

`{ EmbedManager.embed({ key: "key", width: "100%" }); }`

Comment: I tried that too but then I get the following error:
 'EmbedManager' is not defined  no-undef